# Want to remove "Compare" from my Template?

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to remove "Compare Feature" from my Site.  Is this request within scope of Forum ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks as usual Marius.  I'll try Haijerome solution (for obviuos reasons), but what does "OVerride" mean in statement below ?  << Override the Abstract Class "Abstract.php" inside app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product >>

Comment: ok - i have executed Haijerome's solution, it has removed "Compare" from HomePage Prod Slider & Catalog Page. It's still visible on QuickShop & Single Prod Page.  PLs help

Comment: Well, there are 5 more answers there. Try an other one.